# How to create a Splash screen without a package in android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobile, splash-screen

I am facing problem while using the package of Splash Screen, Is there any other way I can set up a splash screen without the help of a package (in android)
reference: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

I tried all the possible methods listed in the repo, but still failed to do so either the package is too old now (version upgrade) or maybe some human error at my end.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sure, noted for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good day. I highly recommend this npm package. I used it for a splash screen and it's really amazing, you just need to follow the steps and you are good to go.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash

Comment: I did use the following package but I am facing problem in navigation after splash screen. I will try to raise a question regarding this to help me solve my problem.

Comment: it's a little bit late but yo ucan use the onReady prop in navigationContainer to navigate to the screen that you want

Comment: yea, I did it thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to modify the Android project files directly. Here are the steps.

- Open your React Native project in your preferred code editor.
- Navigate to the `android/app/src/main` directory of your project.
- Create a new directory called drawable if it doesn't already exist.
  This is where you'll store your splash screen image.
- Place your splash screen image (usually a PNG file) inside the
  drawable directory. Make sure to use an image with the correct
  resolution for different screen densities (`mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, `xxxhdpi`).
- Now, you need to modify the `launch_screen.xml` file. If it doesn't
  exist, create it in the `android/app/src/main/res/layout` directory.
  This file will define the layout for your splash screen.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:src="@drawable/splash_screen_image"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

Replace `splash_screen_image` with the actual name of your splash screen image file.

Open the `styles.xml` file located in the `android/app/src/main/res/values` directory. Add the following style to define the theme for your splash screen:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/launch_screen</item>
</style>
```

Now, open the `AndroidManifest.xml` file located in the `android/app/src/main` directory.

Locate the `<activity>` tag with the `android:name=".MainActivity"` attribute.

Add the `android:theme` attribute to the `<activity>` tag, specifying the `SplashTheme` style you defined earlier:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

Save all the modified files and rebuild your Android project by running `react-native run-android` or `./gradlew clean && react-native run-android` in the project root directory.

Comment: Yes I did, but I got the errors of depreciation when I tried to build the project. So I tried using the npm package provided by @Mehdi Khalfallah but now I am facing problem in navigation for which I will raise question.